# Deploying website with backend-script to connect to database

Tags: reactjs, database, deployment, backend

I have developed an e-commerce website in React + Typescript, and am using MongoDB for my database in the backend. Since customers may leave reviews on products, create a profile, buy a product and so on, a database is essential. When I developed the website locally on my PC, I had to start my backend script with "npm start". This ran a file called index.ts, which looked kinda like this:

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { typeDefs } from './typeDefs';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
require('dotenv/config');

// Connection link to the MongoDB database
const MONGODB = process.env.DB_URI;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

async function startApolloServer() {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  // Connect to the MongoDB database
  mongoose.connect(MONGODB).then(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
  });

  // Start the Apollo server
  const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: PORT },
  });

  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
}

startApolloServer();
```

Without the server being up and running, the website would crash. I would run "npm start" in one terminal, and "npm run dev" in another (to start the frontend).

Now, here is my question. When I deploy my website, will the script run on its own? Is there anything I have to do? This is my first time deploying a website, so would be very happy if someone out there who have deployed an e-commerce website with a similar script, or know how to, could help!

Also, this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow so if I didn't provide enough information or did anything wrong, don't hesitate to yell at me :D

Comment: For the server it depends on how you deploy the website. For react part, if it is a SPA then you only need to host the files, nothing else

Comment: Also your question should be more focused. For example that server apollo code is unnecessary, it would be enough to say your frontend and backend are hosted by separate servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No, it's not a SPA, it's a fully functional e-commerce site with user-login, purchases, products and so on. You are right, much of what I said might be unnecesarry,:The main question is how do I make my backend and frontend communicate together once I deploy my website?

Comment: It depends where are you deploying the website? If it is on a platform like `vercel` then most of the time everything will be done automatically for you.